# How to make validation summary show red text and make bullet point not show?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Just a quick question, I want to make the bullet point not show on my validation summary and also I want to make the text red. I was just wondering how to do this, please check my code below.

```
<div class="help-block col-md-12" style="list-style-type:none">
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your call of `ValidationSummary` extension method like this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "custom-validation-summary" })
```

It will add the css class `custom-validation-summary` to the rendered html element which represents the summary, and than you can change the look with css:

```
<style>
.custom-validation-summary ul {
   list-style-type:none;
   color: red;
   padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

Here is simple MVC fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/wTZbmb

Comment: Where do i change the css? @xxxmatko

Comment: Just add that css in the html page using ``style`` element: ``<style>.custom-validation-summary{}</style>``

Comment: like this @xxxmatko <style>
.custom-validation-summary {
   list-style-type:none;
   color: red;
</style>

Comment: Just did that now the text is red however the bullet point still appears? @xxxmatko

Comment: Sorry, I made little mistake, see my last edit, I've appended the css rule with ``ul`` element so now it is ``.custom-validation-summary ul`` and it should be working

Comment: Bulet point is gone now, however i want it to go left the text @xxxmatko

Comment: I've created a simple fiddle for you https://dotnetfiddle.net/OlB6ut so you can see how it works. By saying "go left the text" I assume that you want to get rid of the padding, so add ``padding: 0;`` to the existing rule.